# C++ Node Deletion Between List Logic

Tags: c++, nodes

EDIT: Problem:  Deleting a node between 2 nodes, and then linking the outer nodes with each other.

After learning and building several quadtrees and octrees, and really liking subdivision, I decided to use subdivision in my server.  But, only placing nodes within themselves.  My problem is, I cant figure out how to link the previous node, to the next one if the node is in the middle.  I am wondering if I am doing this correctly.  Below is my code and I comment where the problem area is.  Any help would be great!

```
bool deleteNode ( SOCKET s , client_information_class *prev ) {
          bool return_value = false;
          if ( node[0]->client_socket != s ) {
               if ( node[0]->node != NULL ) {
                    return_value = node[0]->deleteNode ( s , *node );
               } else {
                    cout << endl << "Can not call deleteNode anymore ... Did not find the node to delete ... " << endl;
                    return return_value;
               }
          } else {
               if ( node[0]->client_state == 1 )
                    InterlockedDecrement(&connection_count);
               if ( node[0]->node != NULL ) {          // there is a next node
                    client_information_class **next = node[0]->node;
                    if ( next[0]->node != NULL ) {
                         // problem area
                         cout << endl << "next[0]->node is not null" << endl;
                         prev->node = next[0]->node[0]->node; // ??? I know its wrong
                    } else {
                         // problem area
                         cout << endl << "next[0]->node is null" << endl;
                         prev->node = next[0]->node;  // ??? I know its wrong
                    }
                    delete node;
               } else {                                   // its the last one
                    prev->node = NULL;
                    delete node;
               }
               InterlockedDecrement(&socket_count);
               return_value = true;
          }
          return return_value;
}
```

Comment: `std::list` not good enough for you?

Comment: @DeadMG What I am doing is like a linked-list, but I am actually inserting nodes into each other much like a quadtree and octree, except this is a onetree (I suppose).  Isnt that different from a linked-list?

Comment: why not step through the code with a debugger, then you can examine variables and experiment with them to see what might be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I got your problem right, you have a trouble inserting an item inside a linked list. I really really hope this is the issue, otherwise all the typing I've done was totally in vain.

I didn't really get all of your code (since it's a little out of context), but I'll show you the logic on an example. I will use nodes that have the following structure:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node * next_;
    Node * prev_;
    int i;//we need this to tell nodes apart. 
    //And whatever data you want.
}
```

So we will make a linked list in which each item has pointers to the previous and the next items. The logic for more complicated structures (like if you have, for example, *left* + *right* + *child* + *parent* pointers) is the same, the only difference is that you will have to set all of them. It doesn't really change much.

So, to construct the list, we will need a couple of constructors that will handle different operations:

the *default constructor* to make an empty node:

```
Node()//default constructor
{
    prev_ = nullptr;
    next_ = nullptr;
    i = 0;
}
```

a constructor that takes a pointer to the last item in the list, and appends itself to the end of the list:

```
Node( Node * prev )//constructor for appending to the end of the list
{
    prev_ = prev;
    next_ = nullptr;//we append to the end, so there is no "next" element
prev->next_ = this;
    i = 0;
}
```

And finally a constructor to insert in the middle (which, I believe, is what you want):

```
Node( Node * prev, Node * next)//Inserting between prev and next nodes
{
    prev->next_ = this;
    next->prev_ = this;
    this->prev_ = prev;
    this->next_ = next;
    i = 0;
}
```

Now we have the full set of instruments to do whatever we want. The one last thing is deleting a node:

```
void deleteNode( Node * deleteMe )
{
    deleteMe->prev_->next_ = deleteMe->next;
    deleteMe->next_->prev_ = deleteMe->prev;
    delete deleteMe;
}
```

or, a more readable syntax:

```
void deleteNode( Node * deleteMe )
{
    Node * prevNode = deleteMe->prev_;
    Node * nextNode = deleteMe->next_;
    prevNode->next_ = deleteMe->next;
    nextNode->prev_ = deleteMe->prev;
    delete deleteMe;
}
```

let's make a sample list of, say, 10 elements:

```
int main()
{
    Node * root =  new Node();//the root of the list. it never changes.
    Node * last = root;//The pointer to the last element
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Node * tmp = new Node( last );
        last = tmp;
    }
}
```

Here, all the elements in the list are properly linked, and have their *i* field containing 0 value. Let's insert another element somewhere in the middle, for example, between the third and the fourth elements:

```
Node * thirdNode = root->next_->next_;//I know this sucks, but it's just an example.
Node * insertMe = new Node(thirdNode, thirdNode->next_);//inserting between the third and the fourth.
insertMe->i = 9;//this will indicate the one we inserted, since all the others will have this as 0.
```

Now we can easily check if the insertion went correctly. Let's type all the element's data:

```
for( Node * it = root; it!= last; it = it->next_)
{
    std::cout << it->i << " ";
}
```

The result will be `0 0 0 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`.

Finally, let's delete the just-inserted node:

```
deleteNode( insertMe );
```

If you will not output the values in the same vay, you will see only zeroes, which means the node was successfully deleted.

If you have more pointers in your nodes, all you have to do is to handle them properly in the same way. Another hint for you is to avoid constructions like `this->next->next->prev`. It is hard to tell that you are referring to the "prev" pointer of the element that is third from the current one. Instead, use something like:

```
Node * target = this->next->next;//easy to read
```

or maybe

```
Node * target = this;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    target = target->next;
```

and then work with the pointer you got.

Comment: :'( I feel really bad.  The problem is deleting a node between 2 nodes.  I'm sorry.  Ill edit my post.  Although, a very nice refresher!

Comment: @Ohmages, I've added that part too =)

Comment: The problem is each node is inserted(subdivided) into itself.  So making a list of lets say: 0(root)-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9.  If I delete 2, then 1 does not point to 3.  Should I upload how I do this?  Edit: let me check out the code all the way, sorry.

Comment: I can make it so the previous node and the next node link up, making leaked memory, but when I go to delete the node, I get a nasty _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->NBlockUse).  This only happens if there is another node after the node I want to delete.  If the node is the last node in the list, its fine.

Comment: Hey, I want to thank you for posting this, it made me figure out that I was allocating memory wrong, and can now delete everything!  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove elements from a singly-linked list easily, then use pointers to pointers like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Code example:

```
// Remove the node from the list:
Node* node_to_remove = *pointer_to_next_pointer;
*pointer_to_next_pointer = node_to_remove->next;

// Destroy the node.
destroy(node_to_remove);
```

This can be done without checking whether you're removing from the head or anything like that.

Full example:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Start by pointing to the head pointer.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//    (next_ptr)
//         |
//         v
// [head]----->[..]----->[..]----->[..]----->[to_remove]----->[....]
Node** next_ptr = &list->head;

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Search the list for the matching entry.
// After searching:
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                  (next_ptr)
//                                       |
//                                       v
// [head]----->[..]----->[..]----->[..]----->[to_remove]----->[next]
while (*next_ptr != to_remove) // or (*next_ptr)->val != to_remove->val
{
    Node* next_node = *next_ptr
    next_ptr = &next_node->next;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Dereference the next pointer and set it to the next node's next
// pointer.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                           (next_ptr)
//                                                |
//                                                v
// [head]----->[..]----->[..]----->[..]---------------------->[next]
*next_ptr = to_remove->next;
```

The trick to simplifying this that most people miss causing them to write 2 or 3 times the code with extra branching is to use a pointer to a pointer to a node, not a pointer to a node.

Also if you don't want to have cache misses galore when iterating through a linked list, make sure to allocate them in a way where you gain back the spatial locality that linked lists typically lack. An easy way to do this without reaching for custom memory allocators is to just link nodes together in an array (or `std::vector`, e.g.) using indices rather than pointers. That can also halve the memory usage of the links on 64-bit if 32-bit indices suffice.